# Swift reading PDF Rich Text Content Control

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

In Microsoft Word, I have created a document that has content controls (like a Rich Text Content Control with a name of "Project.Name", or a Check Box Content Control with a name of "Project.Active"). This word document has been converted to a PDF file. This is the way I control a document on a project & using a Swift file, I want to read these values in iOS.

I have managed to read all the text on the document using:

```
let urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "xx", withExtension: "pdf")

if let pdf = PDFDocument(url: urlPath!) { 
  let pageCount = pdf.pageCount

  for i in 0 ..< pageCount {
    guard let page = pdf.page(at: i) else { continue }
    guard let pageContent = page.attributedString else { continue }
    documentContent.append(pageContent)
    print(pageContent)
```

But what I want to do is to read just the value of the, I assume, key value pair. I have tried using

```
let value = pdf.value(forKey: "Project.Name")
```

Has anyone been able to solve this?